# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm integrating a filter that extracts the initials of a user from the database. The weird thing is, it actually works. But I my console doesn't like it and I don't like red text in my console lol. I tried this in two different ways

Option 1.

```
    (function ()
    {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app.core')
            .filter('shortName', shortName);

        /** @ngInject */
        function shortName() {
            return function(fullName) {
                var name = fullName;
                var inls = name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
                inls = ((inls.shift() || '') + (inls.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
                return inls;
            };
        }


    })();
```

Option 2.

```
    return function(fullName) {
        var shortName="",
        nameTokens = [];
        nameTokens = fullName.split(" ");
        nameTokens.forEach(
            function(token){
                 shortName+=token[0]
            });
        return shortName;
    };
```

But either one I do, although they work, they give me the same error either on `.match` or `.split`. How do I get rid of this? What am I doing wrong?

So far every record online is pointing to a problem with Morris json, but this has nothing todo with Morris.

The result is simple. User creates an account and enters a name. The system creates an avatar with the initials. Very similar to Microsoft.

CODEPEN [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/bqONOJ)

Thanks in advance

Comment: with the given error it is clear that, name is undefined.

Comment: How are you passing `fullName` into your filter function?

Comment: your filter works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/IEbItxEGN4lZFTb9I3S6?p=preview.  the error you are getting seems to indicate that you are incorrectly applying the filter in your code.  What's strange is that you *suggest* the filter works.  Are you sure you don't have a name collision with some other property called `shortName`?

Comment: @Claies The filter works in the very same way as yours does. I don't think there is a name collision. I changed every variable name I'm using in the filter and it still works but also throws the error.

Comment: it's clearly not throwing an error in the plunker I used, so more of your code is necessary to identify what might be causing the error to happen.

Comment: @BenBeck The name is injected in a json and is being pulled from there this way {{vm.contacts.getById(vm.chatContactId).name | shortName}}

Comment: @Claies I could provide whatever you'd like, but keep in mind there are a lot of dependencies. I can't just submit one section of code and expect it to run.

Comment: @LOTUSMS, can you ensure your function `vm.contacts.getById(vm.chatContact.Id).name` is actually returning a value? Judging by the error, I would guess it's actually returning `undefined`.

Comment: unless you are actually passing `undefined` to your filter, it shouldn't throw an error.  given the fact that you still say the filter works and doesn't work at the same time, I would have to *make a guess* that you have it on the page more than once, and one of the times it is being called `undefined` is passed to it.  I updated the plunker to show this in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/IEbItxEGN4lZFTb9I3S6?p=preview

Comment: @BenBeck it does. without the filter ' | shortName' it returns the full name associated with it in the json file

Comment: @Claies. I did a Find All for shortName. I am using it in four ocassions in 3 pages and all correct. Nothing undefined. When I remove the filter, I get their names and console is clear. When I add the filter back, I get the initials. And the console error to go with it.

Comment: you'll have to create a [mcve] showing this exact behavior, because that isn't logical.

Comment: It is contradictory to provide Minimal Complete and Verifiable examples when it comes to angular apps. For it all to work, I would have to provide you with a view, a controller, a module, a json file, so and so forth. Unless I do a single JS file to group it all together with it isn't the exact environment I have. I can send you a complete and verifiable, but not minimal

Comment: it's not contradictory;  In just a few moments I created a functional example of your filter without any errors, and created an alternate with a possible culprit to your problem.  In the course of *attempting* to recreate the problem, you will likely slowly integrate more of your code into the sample, and at some point your sample will trigger the problem.  This is **very likely** to immediately alert you to your issue and a solution without ever having to come back here, but even if it doesn't, it will give others something other than "that's not how it's supposed to work".

Comment: @Claies That's my point. I can put it in an example in a codepen but it will probably work. For me to replicate my error I have to do the exact same thing I am doing in my app.

Comment: well then if we aren't working on your app with you, how are we supposed to know what your app does differently than a codepen?  The situation you are describing **just plain doesn't make sense**, so the only way for someone else to tell you why it is happening is to **see the problem in action**.

Comment: See the edit in my question. I think I may have the error showing in a quick codepen I built